# How to get the main function to call the other program

Tags: python

I have this issue I did where the replace function calls the uppercase function, what I need to do is, I need the main function to call the other functions(SO first the uppercase and then the replace). I also need to change the interactive area. What I mean by this is right now the uppercase function is asking the user for a string, but I need the main function to ask the user for a string and then call the uppercase function and then call replace function.

```
def uppercase():
cap_letters = input("Please enter your string here: ")
new_uppercase=''
for letters in cap_letters:
    if ord(letters) > 96:
        new_uppercase += chr(ord(letters)-32)
    else:
        new_uppercase += letters
print(new_uppercase)
return new_uppercase
```

def replace():

```
old,new = [],[]
newString = ""
new_uppercase = uppercase()
string = new_uppercase
char = input("Change: ")
toThis = input("Change " + char + " to this: ")

for x in range(0,len(string)):
    old.append(string[x])

for y in range(0,len(old)):
    if old[y] != char:
        new.append(old[y])
    else:
        new.append(toThis)

for z in range(0,len(new)):
    newString+=new[z]
print(newString)


def main():
print("Hello, And Welcome to this Slang Program")
uppercase()
# write the part of the program that interacts with the user here
replace()
```

main()

Comment: To clarify: you want main() to request the input, and then pass that input to the replace(), which will then pass that input to uppercase()?

Comment: You've identified what you need to do, and apparently what lines of code you need to do it.  Where are you stuck?  Move the code where you need it to be.
Also, please see [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): most of your post has nothing to do with the question you ask.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for your question. I think you have some formatting issues in your question. Fixing those could make the code easier to read. Here's a helpful post on that https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass values between functions. You need to `return` the values from each function so that the parent function can use them. Passing values around works like this:

```
def function2(foo):
    double_foo = foo * 2 # Do something to create whatever output you need
    return double_foo

def function1(bar):
    foobar = function2(bar) # Note that the foo and bar variables here are locally scoped 
    return foobar

def main():
    user_input = input("Please enter your string here: ")
    output = function1(user_input)
    return output

main()
```

For more on scoping, check out https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/global_scope.html